# Detecting when only silence is being played

Tags: alsa

My PC is connected to an audio amplifier that I can switch on or off over the network.  I would like to set things up to switch it off automatically after no audio has been playing for 10 minutes.

I found some similar questions here which advised looking at `/proc/asound/card*/pcm*/sub*/status` to check for the word `RUNNING` which indicates audio is being output, however many programs seem to leave their audio running even when they aren't making any noise, just outputting silence.  I have noticed that some Python programs do this, as does Firefox when run through `apulse`.

This means that I cannot detect via `/proc/asound/` when there is no audio coming out of the speakers, as it is permanently `RUNNING`.

Is there another way to detect when the only audio signal being played is silence?  Is there some way to record or otherwise intercept ALSA output, even when a `hw` device is the one in use?

Comment: `sox` has an *effect* which can detect silence, and stop, but you would have to pipe your sound data through it. Aren't you using pulseaudio?

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to investigate that then.  No I had trouble getting pulseaudio working when I tried a few years ago and now I'm not sure what it does that ALSA doesn't do already so not sure why I'd need it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proof of concept demonstration using just alsa, the alsa loopback module, and `sox` to detect silence. The loopback module provides you with an output device that you can play sound into, and then record back from it. So, for example, you could direct `mplayer` to use the loopback for sound output, then run `sox` to record from the loopback, detect silence, and output to the original hardware output device.

Load the module with

```
sudo modprobe snd-aloop
```

(It was in my list of available kernel modules). `aplay -l` will now list a new card with 2 devices. Device 0 is to play into, device 1 to record from. There are 8 independent "subdevice" channels, and it is easiest to use number 0 as often it can be then be omitted. (I found `aplay` in package `alsa-utils`).

```
$ aplay -l
...
card 1: Loopback [Loopback], device 0: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
...
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: Loopback [Loopback], device 1: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
...
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
```

You can now use another utility from the package to generate a continuous tone into the loopback device 0 (subdevice 0):

```
speaker-test -t sine -D hw:Loopback
```

or for example tell `mplayer` to use the device with option `-ao alsa:device=hw=Loopback`

You will hear nothing until you also run `sox` getting it to read the other side of the device and write it to the real hardware, assuming this is card 0:

```
sox -q  -t alsa hw:Loopback,1  -t alsa hw:0  silence 0 1 10.0 2%
```

(I saw quite a few warnings *sox WARN alsa: under-run*). If you stop the speaker test, after 10 seconds of silence the `sox` command will stop.
Note, if you mute `mplayer` you get silence but this seems to be independent of the data level (which you can visualise if you remove the `-q` from `sox`). You need to pause or lower the sound level of `mplayer` to have the silence detected. `sox` may also introduce a second or two of delay in the audio. You should be able to configure alsa to make the Loopback device the default instead of your card 0.

A more satisfactory solution is to let the kernel sound drivers handle the real-time audio, and use `sox` only to detect the silence, throwing away its output.  This seems to be possible, but with just alsa it is also a bit complicated and needs knowledge I don't have, though you can find examples of duplicating sound to two devices, your original audio card, and a virtual device which `sox` can then read.

A simpler solution using pulseaudio to enable *monitoring* is possible, using `pactl load-module module-combine-sink` which I will probably investigate.